# MS Access SQL How to put a table name as Variable (how to run one query for multiple tables)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Lets say I have a query like this:

```
Parameters Table_Name string, Field_Name string;

Update Table_Name Set Table_Name.[field1] = "new value", Table_Name.[field2] = "new Value" Where Table_Name.[Field_Name] = "Some value"
```

Basically I have the same query which I need to run against different tables which share some fields together. I want to be able to type the table name when I run the query.

I know this can be achieved with VBA, but this way would be a lot easier than VBA. Although VBA is also welcome but I would like to be able to do this in pure SQL.

How to achieve the above logic for table names AND field names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this being done in MSAccess or in SQL Server?  If you've got a SQL Server behind things, then you'll be looking to do some [`sp_executesql` calls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) to get the job done.  If you're doing this in MSAccess, you can accomplish the same by building dynamic SQL statements in VBA - either way would work if you've got Access pointing to SQL, though.